# Tras realizar un insert intento ejecutar una select con Spring JDBC. No obtengo el resultado

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Tras conseguir insertar datos con un insert en Spring JDBC, trato de realizar una consulta sobre los datos de ese insert. Siempre me devuelve la select como que no encuentra resultados. Esa misma select la uso en otro lado del código y funciona perfectamente. Y el insert sí me inserta datos. De hecho, he probado a actualizar la base de datos y sí está almacenando datos. La consola no me arroja ninguna excepción, salvo a la hora de intentar obtener el objeto que trato de recuperar de la select, pues lo utilizo en una página de Thymeleaf.
El código es el siguiente:

```
public class PersonController {
@Autowired
    PersonService personService;    
@PostMapping(value = "createperson")
    public ModelAndView create(@Valid Person createperson, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) throws EmailExistsException, UserExistsException {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return new ModelAndView("registrationperson", "formErrors", result.getAllErrors());
        } 
        Person person = personService.findByUser(userDetailsService.getUserDetails().getUsername());                    
        Person personcreated = personService.save(createperson);
        //projectRegistrationService.saveProjectRegistrations(Arrays.asList(createperson.getProjects()), personcreated);
        model.addAttribute(PERSON, person);
        model.addAttribute("personcreated.id", personcreated.getId()); 
        model.addAttribute("globalMessage", "Successfully created a new person");
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/person/{personcreated.id}", model);
    }
}


@Service
        public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService {
        @Autowired
            PersonRepository personRepository;
    @Autowired
        PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;    
        @Autowired
        ProjectPersonRepository projectPersonRepository;
        @Override
            public Person save(final Person person) throws EmailExistsException, UserExistsException {
                Person personFound = personRepository.findById(person.getId());
                
                if(Objects.nonNull(personFound)) {
                    List<Project> projectsFound = findAllProjectsByPerson(personFound);
                    if (emailExist(person.getEmail()) && !personFound.getEmail().equals(person.getEmail())) {
                        throw new EmailExistsException("There is an account with that email address: " + person.getEmail());
                    }
                    if (userExist(person.getUser()) && !personFound.getUser().equals(person.getUser())) {
                        throw new UserExistsException("There is an account with that username: " + person.getUser());
                    }
                    personRepository.update(person);
                    Person personFoundSaved = personRepository.findById(person.getId());
                    if(Objects.nonNull(person.getProjects()) && person.getProjects().length > 0) {
                        if(Objects.nonNull(projectsFound)){
                            int indexProjects = 0;
                            while(indexProjects < person.getProjects().length && indexProjects < projectsFound.size()) {
                                projectPersonRepository.update(person.getProjects()[indexProjects], personFoundSaved, projectsFound.get(indexProjects), personFound);
                                indexProjects++;
                            }
                            if(indexProjects >= person.getProjects().length) {
                                while(indexProjects < projectsFound.size()) {
                                    projectPersonRepository.delete(projectsFound.get(indexProjects), personFoundSaved);
                                    indexProjects++;
                                }
                            } else if(indexProjects >= projectsFound.size()) {
                                while(indexProjects < person.getProjects().length) {
                                    projectPersonRepository.insert(person.getProjects()[indexProjects], personFoundSaved);
                                    indexProjects++;
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            for(int indexProjects = 0; indexProjects < person.getProjects().length; indexProjects++) {                      
                                projectPersonRepository.insert(person.getProjects()[indexProjects], personFoundSaved);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (emailExist(person.getEmail())) {
                        throw new EmailExistsException("There is an account with that email address: " + person.getEmail());
                    }
                    if (userExist(person.getUser())) {
                        throw new UserExistsException("There is an account with that username: " + person.getUser());
                    }
                    person.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(person.getPassword()));
                    personRepository.insert(person);
                    Person personSaved = personRepository.findByUser(person.getUser());
                    if(Objects.nonNull(person.getProjects()) && person.getProjects().length > 0) {
                        for(int indexProjects = 0; indexProjects < person.getProjects().length; indexProjects++) {
                            projectPersonRepository.insert(person.getProjects()[indexProjects], personSaved);
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                return findByUser(person.getUser());
            }
        }

@Repository
public class PersonRepository {
@Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate template;
    @Autowired
    RoleRepository roleRepository;
private static final String MADRID_ZONE_ID = "Europe/Madrid";
    /**
     * @param template
     */
    public PersonRepository(JdbcTemplate template) {
        super();
        this.template = template;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void insert(Person person) {
        LocalDate localDateStartDate = new Date().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.of(MADRID_ZONE_ID))
                .toLocalDate();
        String query = "insert into person (dni, email, lastname1, lastname2, name, password, start_date, user, role_id) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";
        template.update(query, 
                        person.getDni(),
                        person.getEmail(),
                        person.getLastname1(),
                        person.getLastname2(),
                        person.getName(),
                        person.getPassword(),               
                        localDateStartDate,
                        person.getUser(),
                        person.getRole().getId());
    }
public Person findByUser(String user) {
        String query = "SELECT p.id, p.dni, p.email, p.end_date, p.start_date, p.lastname1, p.lastname2, p.name, p.password, p.user, r.id as role_id FROM person p, role r WHERE p.user = ? AND p.role_id = r.id;";
        List<Person> persons = template.query(query, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Person>(Person.class), user);
        Person person = null;
        if(Objects.nonNull(persons) && !persons.isEmpty()) {
            person = persons.get(0);
            Role role = roleRepository.findById(person.getRoleId());
            person.setRole(role);
        }
        return person;
    }
}
```

Comment: Rodrigo, dentro del servicio tienes dos metodos que obtienen el usuario. Hay uno que no está (o al menos no veo) el código. Justo la linea siguiente al insert, estas llamando al repo para que te traiga la info de la persona en el objeto "personSaved", pero para el return llamas a un método "findByUser" que está directo del servicio. ¿lo unico que hace es llamar al repo?

Comment: Buenas Franco, efectivamente llamo sin querer a personRepository. Tengo un método de findByUser dentro de PersonServiceImpl que retorna personRepository.findByUser(user);

Comment: fíjate que en el controller estas llamando find user antes del save y si todavía no existe, no va a retornar la persona.

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT p.id, p.dni, p.email, p.end_date, p.start_date, p.lastname1, p.lastname2, p.name, p.password, p.user, r.id as role_id FROM person p, role r WHERE p.user = ? AND p.role_id = r.id;";
```

La respuesta está en que las consultas están mal. Si quiero obtener un usuario para qué hago ese WHERE? no tiene sentido. Ya me funciona.

Ha sido la falta de sueño. Hay que dormir más.

Muchas gracias Franco por molestarte en ver mi código (también lo he refactorizado, que era un buen potaje y gracias por el consejo :) )
Saludos!